# Git equivalent of which/whence

Tags: git, shell, alias

When I run `git help -a` it shows me the list of internal commands, all of my aliases, and all of my external git commands (i.e. any executable starting with `git-` in my path). What I'd like is an alias or script that I can run as `git which` that will tell me one of the following:

- command not found (e.g. `git which notacommand`)
- built-in command (e.g. `git which checkout`)
- the full path to the command (e.g. `git which pwd` would show `/usr/local/bin/git-pwd`)
- the alias text (e.g. `git which wtf` would show `alias.wtf blame -w`)

I could write a script pretty easily to use the output of `git help -a` and produce this, but is there some git command I'm missing that already provides some or all of this functionality?

### Update

Thanks to the comment and answer from @jthill I came up with the following `git-which` script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

if test $# -ne 1
then
        echo "Usage: $0 <git command>" >&2
        exit 1
fi

CMD=git-"$1"

if PATH="$(git --exec-path)" command -v "$CMD" >/dev/null
then
    echo "$1: git built-in command"
    exit 0
elif command -v "$CMD"
then
    exit 0
elif git config --get-regexp '^alias\.'"$1"'$' |\
    sed 's/^alias\.\([^\s]\+\)/\1: aliased to /'
then
        exit 0
fi

echo "$1 not found"
exit 1
```

Comment: `git help` already shows you aliases, `git --exec-path` shows you where the built-in git commands live. So `PATH=$PATH:$(git --exec-path) which git-checkout` will do 1, 2 and 3 for you.

Comment: @jthill You should make that an answer. It was enough to get me on the right path.

Comment: looking for builtins only in git-core will miss any commands you've installed elsewhere in your path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git help` will show you aliases, say `git help wtf` and it'll say `'wtf' is aliased to 'blame -w'`. For the rest, hunting up libexec/git-core isn't hard, say `git --exec-path`, and `which` already hunts up commands, so

```
PATH=$(git --exec-path):$PATH which git-checkout
```

will do your hunting for you, aliases can't override builtins so (fingers-to-textbox warning:)

```
f() { PATH=$(git --exec-path)${PATH+:$PATH} which git-$1 2>&- || git help $1; }
```

looks like a decent start.